# Problem exporting a Unity project for iOS and building it on XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, game-development

Can somebody help me? I have a problem exporting a Unity project for iOS and building it on XCode. I have these kind of errors when I try to build in my XCode.

I tried changing the architecture and doing pod init + pod install and opening .xcworkspace. But errors are still there...

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzjEn.png)